# Rendering ReactJS component from jQuery without ReactDOM.render

Tags: jquery, reactjs

I'm currently using a jquery plugin that creates the element from raw HTML e.g.

```
'<div data-react-class="ContactSelect" data-react-props="{&quot;selectedItem&quot;:null}"></div>'
```

However, react isn't properly detecting this new component. Is there an event or function I can call to react-ify this element?

Answer (score 0):

React is only aware components it renders itself. Elements created elsewhere aren't React elements. If you need more information, read about the virtual DOM, or shadow DOM.

If you ReactDOM.render component(s) at the same place in the DOM tree, it will do the diff checking with node(s) already there, then track the new component(s), but you have to go through React.

Comment: But then what happens to elements rendered by the server? Aren't they also native elements that get turned into react components? React actually renders the component properly if I include that in the original HTML and not loading dynamically, which makes me think that React does what I want on page load.

Comment: What happens is React generates a string (renderToString), which is generated only as markup, not a virtual DOM component. Client-side React is not aware of these elements. When the client-side components are loaded in the same spots on the node tree, it does the diff checking and initializes things like event handlers, etc.

Comment: Even copy and pasting that resultant html without going through react properly loads the component though. It's just that I can't seem to do this dynamically after the page has loaded.

Comment: Consider me stumped. Unrelated question: What's keeping you from using React on the client side, if I may ask?

Comment: I'm actually using a gem https://github.com/nathanvda/cocoon that helps to render form fields (e.g. adding/removing rows dynamically). It takes in a server-side partial which for us, contains the react component.